# JavaPsiScanner doesn't see calls

Tags: android-lint

I'm working on a custom Lint check and can't get all the method calls I need.

What I need: access to every `add()` call in lines like this:

`Builder.from(arg)
        .add(arg1, arg2)
        .add(arg1, arg2)
        .add(arg1, arg2);`

What I get: `visitMethod` is not called at all. In such lines it's only called for 'from()'.

Detector code sample:

```
public class ExampleDetector extends Detector implements Detector.JavaPsiScanner {
    @Override
    public List<String> getApplicableMethodNames() {
        return Collections.singletonList("add");
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethod(JavaContext context, @Nullable JavaElementVisitor visitor,
                            @NonNull PsiMethodCallExpression call, @NonNull PsiMethod method) {
        ...
    }
    ....

}
```

How can I solve it? Why is it not visited at all?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry not really, postponed it for a while. If you figure out how to make it work, please, share :)